# Как создать такую фигуру на css?

Tags: css, css3, веб-дизайн, дизайн, design

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как создать такую фигуру на css?

Comment: `position: absolute;` и `border-radius` вам помогут

Answer (score 1):

Такую фигуру создать совсем не сложно. Сложность может возникнуть только в одном моменте, это внутренний угол, сверстать который нужно таким образом, чтобы он не зависел от общего фона на странице. Это в случае, если не планируется фон одного цвета. В моем примере этот элемент не зависит от общего фона. Для демонстрации применил разноцветный фон. Пользуйтесь на здоровье. Успехов!

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('https://vk.vkfaces.com/850628/v850628886/32d55/HHAsvfpat6M.jpg') right bottom no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #4260aa;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.right>span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: #4260aa;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.corner {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  bottom: 40px;
  right: 120px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.corner:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -12px;
  right: -12px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom: 12px solid #4260aa;
  border-right: 12px solid #4260aa;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="right">30<span>НЕТ 2020</span></div>
  <div class="bottom">Оформляется</div>
  <div class="corner"></div>
</div>
```